# How to process files based on the creation/modified time in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have files with some random names such as 'HistoryData130818049895663415'. This file was last modified on Monday 24 April 2017 02:41:04 PM IST. Based on the modified time how can i process the file.

for e.g, i want to process all the files which was modified between 01 JAN 2016 to 01 JAN 2017, both dates inclusive.

Did anyone tried similar scenarios to process files??

Comment: You attempted something for yourself? let us know your attempts even it failed, we can guide you the right way

Comment: If you are suggesting any tools which in _tags_ or question, let us know its version, usually found by doing `<command> --version`, for e.g. `bash --version`

Comment: Have you tried with `find`? https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Age-Ranges

Comment: I tried ls -laR | grep <month>, but this is returning files for month for every year. e.g: ls -laR | grep Apr returns files for Apr from each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
find /searchdir -type f -newermt 2016-01-01 ! -newermt 2017-01-01 -exec <processing cmds> {} \;
```

Where you can replace your processing cmd (mv, rm etc) and `mt` refers modification time of file.